# App Pool memory

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

My App pool is taking like 180mb to 220mb at any given time.
It sometimes goes down to 80mb but comes back to 180mb in few mins.
Is this behaviour normal? If the memory usage seems high, how can i reduce it?

We have like 500 employees of which at any given time atleast 200 employees will be working on that particular website.

I am using IIS 7.0, windows server 2008, Asp.net 3.5

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Abhi

Comment: I should also mention that we have like 6 App Pools on the same server and atleast 5 of them take more than 150Mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your App Pool in IIS and choose `Advance Settings...` then scroll down and look for `Private Memory Limit (KB)` and `Virtual Memory Limit (KB)` near the very bottom. However like @BNL suggests your usage is nothing to really be concerned about.

Comment: Ya i just looked at those. Both are at 0kb

Comment: That's the default - it means there is no limit.

Comment: Ohk. I ask because recently our site is going up and down. Like really slow a second and back to normal next second. Wasnt sure if App pool was any reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally dependent on your site. 180-220 mb is nothing. On 32bit windows you have to worry around 600mb. 64bit windows, it can be much higher.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the behavior you describe sounds normal. Garbage collection, among other things, can cause periodic fluctuations in memory use.

Unless your server is starting to page excessively, I wouldn't restrict the memory available to the AppPools. Internal ASP.NET features such as caching work better when they have plenty of memory available.

If you're concerned that the memory use is higher than it should be, then consider running your apps through a memory profiler, to find out how the memory is being used.